# MediaPlayer.start does not play music

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am making a music app and I am using the external storage that is in my phone to access the data through the app. Although I have been able to add the music as a list view, when I attempt to make the music play on "onItemClickListener" the mp3 file that is chosen does not play.

here is my code for choosing specific item:

```
public void doStuff(){
    listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MusicList);
    arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    getMusic();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraylist );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // open music player to play desired song
            mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                }


            });
            mediaplayer.start();




            }
```

Lastly, here is the error on the Logcat:

```
 07-02 18:17:12.327 21863-21863/com.example.daniel.queuemusic V/MediaPlayer-JNI: start
07-02 18:17:12.327 21863-21863/com.example.daniel.queuemusic V/MediaPlayerNative: start
07-02 18:17:12.327 21863-21863/com.example.daniel.queuemusic E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x0)
07-02 18:17:12.327 21863-21863/com.example.daniel.queuemusic V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
    notify(100, -38, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
```

this same error happens each time I click on an item(mp3 file) on the list.

I've checked online but so far I haven't been able to figure it out. If anyone could give me any advice I would really Appreciate it!

Comment: 1) Add the tag for the language, not the IDE, and always carefully read the tag pop-up before adding it to a question. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: I don't suppose you are able to help me with my question rather than help me post a question.

Comment: I don't suppose you realize answers appear below in the answer section, while comments are for anything else. Glad I did not waste time in down voting, ***after*** improving the question so that people who follow the [tag:android] tag can find it and (presumably) help answer it.